# Cannot update username value. PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem. When I try to update the Username value via HTML form.
Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="namechanging.php" method="post">

<br>
  <fieldset>
    <span class="ico user-ico"></span>
     <input name="ingamename" type="text" class="field" value="Example: John_Doe" title="Example: John_Doe" />
   </fieldset>
   <center><input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit btn blue-btn" value="Change Name" /></center>
</form>
```

here is my namechanging.php file:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['ingamename'] = $_POST['ingamename']; 
  $newingamename = $_SESSION['ingamename'];
  $nc = $_SESSION['nc'];
  if($nc < 1){
    $updateresult = '<strong>Error:</strong> You do not have any name changes left. Donate for more...'; 
    header("Location: ucp-home-error.php");
  }
  else {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASS","DB-NAME");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $newnc = $nc - 1;

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET Username=$newingamename WHERE Username='$_SESSION[user]' ");
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET NameChanges=$newnc
         WHERE Username='$_SESSION[user]'");
    $updateresult = 'Your In-Game Name was changed successfully. Please re-log!';
    header("Location: ucp-home-success.php");
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
  $_SESSION['updateresult'] = $updateresult;?>
```

It work removing -1 from $nc, but it is not changing the username. You should also know that the username is saved in the session, and that is the username with which I've logged into a authentication page.
here is my auth.php file:

```
<?php
include("sql.php");
session_start();

function Destroy() {
  unset($_SESSION['UID']);
  unset($_SESSION['USERNAME']);
  unset($_SESSION['FULL NAME']);
  header("location: account-log-in-restricted.php");
}

if(isset($_SESSION['UID']) && isset($_SESSION['USERNAME'])) {
  $UID = $_SESSION['UID'];
  $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UID` = '$UID' AND `Username` = '$username'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($qry) != 1) { Destroy(); }
} else { Destroy(); }
?>
```

Comment: Please, before you do **anything** else, learn how to use mysqli [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) correctly by making use of [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). What you're doing here is extremely hazardous and will eventually get you into serious trouble. Also, do not use `mysql_query` unless you have an extremely good reason.

Comment: How about you check whether your queries succeeded before moving forward with questions and debugging?

Comment: you already using `mysqli` and `mysql`.... now use pdo too and finish the recipe for spaghetti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably choking on this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users WHERE Username='$_SESSION[user]' SET Username=$newingamename");
                                                1 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^               2 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In (1), that's the equivalent of saying `$_SESSION[user]` when what you want is `$_SESSION['user']` (with the quotes around `user`).

In (2), you need to put single quotes around the $newingamename.

**Note:** The remainder was edited from the original answer to (a) consolidate the PHP and MySQL fixes and (b) recast using `mysqli` parameter binding for code safety.

Also, the MySQL query is wrong: `SET` comes before `WHERE`.

Putting this all together, and *using `mysqli` binding parameters for code (and career) security*, you get this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'UPDATE users SET username=? WHERE username = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newingamename, $_SESSION['user']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Make similar changes for the other `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. It is still NOT updating the username :( $_SESSION['user'] point to the same value which I would like to edit. Can that cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a MySQL syntax error in your original post. I've added information to my answer; please check the addendum at the bottom. Also, if you have MySQL Workbench or MySQL Command Line, I recommend working out your queries there before incorporating them into PHP - it's a lot easier to debug them there. Also check the PHP mysqli documentation on how to retrieve error information after executing a query - that's another great way to find answers. Good luck!

Comment: Posting queries without proper escaping is like handing someone a loaded gun. Extremely dangerous.

Comment: Fair enough @tadman. As I re-read my answer I see I focused too much on the specifics of why the PHP/MySQL wasn't working and not enough on the broader mission of getting the OP to write better code. Letting the OP off with "you should use mysqli" was lame. My bad.

Comment: It's literally two short lines of code to use `bind_param` and turn this possibly career destroying snippet of code into something safe. You should be able to do that in your sleep, right?

Comment: Not quite in my sleep, but nearly so as it's the end of a very long day :) I've updated my answer. Thanks for stressing this; you're right about how serious binding is. I always use prepared statements in my own code; the SO users deserve no less.